# pycharm virualenv import class from subdirectory

Tags: python, kivy, virtualenv, python-3.6, python-import

I am re-organising one large Kivy for Android with Python 3.6 project into something resembling a MVC structure.  So I have time and decided to create a new PyCharm project vertualenv and start with the main files.  I have a `main.py` and `main.kv` file in the main project directory or `venv` directory that runs the App.  I also created a `models` folder and within this folder a .py file for each `sqlite3` datatable.  When I import the class to my `main.py` file I get `ModuleNotFound` error.   My directory looks like this

```
~/PyCharmProjects/MyProjectName/venv/main.py #main environment
                                    /main.kv
                                    /models/__init__.py #subdirectory
                                           /cattle.py
```

From the `main.py` file I tried importing with the following:

```
from models.cattle import Cattle
from .models.cattle import Cattle
```

This did not work.  I also added a `__init__.py` file inside the `models` directory with no difference.

How can I get the main file to import my custom Cattle class from a subdirectory?

So I solved it.  I don't know why everything was inside the venv directory.  But I just moved the main files and models directory outside of the venv folder and it now imports.